Compare git repos after migrating the hosting services from bitbucket to github
Our organization is migrating git repos from bitbucket to Github.
We have hundreds of repos, and the migration is delegated to the IT team and we developers have to make sure that they are in sync and not metadata like commit history, tags ... are lost
At present I am cloning the repos into two directories and comparing their contents and branches. How can I also compare their commit histories or any other metadata that I must compare?
Looking at ways to automate this very tedious effort.
Here is what I have narrowed it down to ->

Clone source repo into folder source, target into target
Add a local remote to the source folder to point to the target folder.
Run git push local --all --dry-run
Parse the output of the command to find if anything might be out of sync.

Does this take care of also keeping track of the commit histories?

I don't understand the issue. Whether IT is migrating repos that are being worked on or not from, why should they lose commits, branches or tags in the process? If some repos have been cloned and worked on locally by some developers, your colleagues simply need to update the remote's URL  (or add a second one) and perform everything as normal (or make an extra push to the second remote). If some repos have not been worked on in a long time, they're simply migrated. Commits, tags and branches are all part of a repository (Git's object store). They're not specific to a hosting service.

The repos are being continuously worked on but also we would like to independently verify if anything is out of place. I suppose what you are saying makes total sense, but when the stakes are high then we double check.

I understand. You could probably write a script to check that every tag and branch on the old repo exists on the new one as well with git cat-file -e <object-name>. While commit-wise, you could perform a symmetric difference for each branch between the corresponding tracking branch for the old repo and the tracking branch for the new repo git log origin-old/branch...origin-new/branch. This would show any commit not contained in either branch's history.
